# Can you tell how many users are connected to wifi on an android device?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I want to build an android application that tells how many users are connected to a wireless network? Is there a way to do it? Can tcpdump be used? Please suggest some method.

Comment: Is it your network? Do you have admin access to the AP? Or do you want to scan public hotspots?

Comment: No, i dont have admin access to the AP. I want to scan public hotspots to have a measure of numbers of users on various networks.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334244/is-there-any-way-to-put-android-wifi-droid-handset-into-promiscuous-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the goals of the App.

Many enterprise wireless access points have a web service and api running on the device that can be queried against. It should be as simple as setting up a http session on the android app and calling the API or web service through post/get calls. even if the AP does not have an api you should still be able to access the routers state through what ever mechanism is used to set it up.

Comment: How do you access routers state if you are not the admin and just want to know the overview of the network.

Comment: Security wise you should not be able to get that kind of info if you are not admin of the AP. My guess is that you have to write a sniffer of some kind, and it's not that straight forward as far as I know. Reading the link from @dtmilano might give you a few tips.